# Add plot to a given figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a figure in one part of the code as follows:

```
n = arange(51)
fig3 = plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(n,a1mag,'ro')
```

Now, i want to add another plot to this figure at a later part of the code. Is there some way to access fig3 while plotting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be recommendable to either stay completely in the pyplot state-machine or comlpetely in the object oriented API; mixing the two causes just headaches.

#### pyplot

```
plt.figure(3)
plt.semilogy(x,y,'ro')

# .. do other stuff
# reactivate figure 3
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(x,z)
```

#### object-oriented API

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.semilogy(x,y)
# .. do other stuff
# plot to ax3
ax3.plot(x,z)
```