# Overwrite the same plot

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

I need to overwrite the same plot. The code is the following:

Python Version:

```
def plotResults( data, w, C):

N = w.shape[0]
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(10,8) )
plt.scatter( *data.T, marker='.' )
for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(i,N):
        if C[i,j]==1:
            plt.plot( (w[i,0], w[j,0]), (w[i,1], w[j,1]), 'ro-', marker='')
plt.scatter( w[:,0], w[:,1], s = 40,c = 'y', marker = 's', edgecolors='k')
```

MATLAB version:

```
function PlotResults(X, w, C)

N = size(w,1);

plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'.');
hold on;
for i=1:N-1
    for j=i:N
        if C(i,j)==1
            plot([w(i,1) w(j,1)],[w(i,2) w(j,2)],'r','LineWidth',2);
        end
    end
end
plot(w(:,1),w(:,2),'ko','MarkerFaceColor','y','MarkerSize',10);
hold off;
axis equal;
grid on;
```

This function is called in a for loop and it displays the points with the first scatter plot (They are the same at every iteration). 
In the nested for loops I plot red lines between specific points and in the last part of the code I add some yellow circles in order to identify the vertices of the red lines. I also attach the MATLAB version where the three plot are in the same figure and changes happens in the same figure. 
I have tried with some plt.show() or plt.pause() and I also checked some possible solutions that I found in other posts but they are not suitable for my case I think.

Comment: So your problem is with the Python program right ?

Comment: Yes, i would like to have in the same plot the updates. I'd like to post you a video of the MATLAB result but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687158/add-plot-to-a-given-figure-in-matplotlib ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same problem. I need to overwrite in the same plot three different plot every time that i call that function. In MATLAB this is possible thanks to the magic of hold_on() and hold_off()

Comment: In your code you are creating a new figure every time you call plotResults

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I know. I don't know how to obtain the same effect that I have with the MATLAB code. It's not so easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example of what you could do :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotResult(x):
    plt.plot(x,x,'o')

plt.figure()
# Add new plots to the figure
plotResult(1) 
plotResult(2)
plotResult(3)
```